# PHP: get text from in between a string with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm sorry if similar questions have been asked here before, but I wasn't able to accomplish what I was trying to do after hours of research. Also bear in mind, I'm not very familiar with regex / preg_match. Thanks

```
$string  = "<?php include('manage.php'); header('Location: https://google.ca/drive/'); ?>";
```

How would I return only the URL from this string, which is `https://google.ca/drive/`

Comment: Use a regular expression that matches everything after `Location:` until `'`.

Comment: `Location:\s*\K[^'"]+`?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with regex, try `explode("'", explode("Location: ", $string)[1])[0];`

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, noted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable with regex and can guarantee that the string format you've shown is the only format possible then this will work:

```
<?php
$string  = "<?php include('manage.php'); header('Location: https://google.ca/drive/'); ?>";

echo substr( explode( "'", $string )[3], 10 );
```

Comment: @Python19 You're welcome. Feel free to accept my answer as correct if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 preg_match('/(\'|")location:\s*(?P<url>[^\1]+)\1/i', $string, $match);
```

Try it online

https://regex101.com/r/dKors4/1

To explain

- the start and end `/` are just delimiters (I don't know why you need them but you do, they can be other things like `#` etc)
- `('|")` capture group `(...)` single OR double quote
- `location:` literal match
- `\s*` match white space none or more times
- `(?P<url>...)` named capture group, shows up in `$match['url']`, capture the following

  - `[^\1]+` Not `^` character set `[...]` (so don't match whats in here) `+` one or more times,`\1`  Backreference to the first capture group `('|")`. So in English match anything but the quote we found in the first capture group one or more times.
- then we close it up by matching the Backreference to the quotes.
- the `\i` is the ending delimiter and the `i` flag for case insensitive.  You can have `Location:` or `location:` etc.

So to put it all in English:

Find what type of quote we are using, capture it.  Match the string `location:`. Then capture in `url` anything but the quote type we found, ending on that same quote.

Hope that makes sense.